# Show warning message when user delete a row from gridview in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview on a web form. I add a command field to gridview for delete and edit.

I want that when a user click on del button, an alert (warning) message should be shown using javascript:

> Are you sure to delete this record?

When user clicks `Yes`, the record was deleted.

How can I do this?

This is my command field:

```
<asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" 
     CancelImageUrl="~/styles/img/cancel.png" 
     DeleteImageUrl="~/styles/img/trash.png" 
     EditImageUrl="~/styles/img/edit.png" 
     ItemStyle-Width="50px" 
     ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" 
     UpdateImageUrl="~/styles/img/update.gif">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `OnClientClick` property on the Delete button to connect it to a javascript.

```
<asp:Button ID="deleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"
OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete this record?');" />
```

Here is a [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1045957.aspx/1) that explains more.

Comment: I would break the two buttons up in template fields insteed to have custom javascripts to each of the buttons. Also look att this stackoverflow question and answer for guidiense http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000337/adding-a-javascript-confirmation-prompt-to-a-delete-command-button-in-an-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for execution...

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="delete" 
Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you Want to Delete this   Record?');" 
CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") %>'>
</asp:LinkButton>`
```