# Confirmation dialog box on CommandField click

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` in ASP.NET which has a `<asp:CommandField/>` inside it. This `CommandField` is a button which deletes that row from the `GridView`, but when it is clicked I want a dialog box to appear letting the user know it has been deleted.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" CssClass="gv1" ID="gv_PendingRequests" HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDeleting="gv_PendingRequests_RowDeleting" DataKeyNames="RECORD_ID">
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6a3d98" ForeColor="White" Height="20" />
                        <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Height="20px" />
                        <AlternatingRowStyle Height="20px" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="RECORD_ID" Visible="false"  />
                            <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" DataField="START_DATE" HeaderText="Start Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
                            <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" DataField="END_DATE" HeaderText="End Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
                            <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" DataField="DAYS" HeaderText="Days"  />
                            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton ="true" DeleteText="Remove Request"/>

                        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This is my `.aspx` code, I have looked around before asking this question and people have mentioned something about `OnRowDataBound` in the C# but I could get it to work.

**FOUND ANSWER**

I added this to my .aspx page.

```
OnRowDeleting="gv_AcceptedRequests_RowDeleting"
```

and from there when i deleted the message using the CommandField it hit my event in c#.

Then in C# i added this code to display a dialog box.

```
string message = "Request cancelled.";

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + message + "');", true);
```

Comment: Possible dublicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317694/how-to-add-delete-confirmation-prompt-for-command-field-in-detail-view .... Have found it after 1 google-search

Comment: @DatRid Fair enough, I didn't see that question. They are using a LinkButton though but ill give it a try anyway.

Comment: Otherwise you can try thisone: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000337/adding-a-javascript-confirmation-prompt-to-a-delete-command-button-in-an-asp-net?rq=1 Actually i don't see a possibility to do this with Command Field. Its definitely possible with Link Buttons, used it often in my code.

Comment: In a codebehind, rowdatabound event try for CommandField.control.Attributes("onclick","yourJsFunctionToCall");

Comment: @Murali This doesn't work as you cannot do .Control.

Comment: @DatRid Ill have an attempt as a LinkButton and let you know.

Comment: @DatRid I answered my own question and edit my answer.

Comment: yes that's fine. You can also post it as answer and accept it.